# Updating a table row, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I need to update a certain row in table, already did "validators" to assure 1 row edit when checkbox is checked after clicking some other button, so far i wrote something like:

```
$("#btnsavechanges").click(function(){


    $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children)(.eq(0).append(document.getElementById("modsub").value);
    $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children)(.eq(2).append(document.getElementById("modwhere").value);
    $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children)(.eq(3).append(document.getElementById("modwhen").value);
    $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children)(.eq(4).append(document.getElementById("modtime").value);
    $("#meetingspanel tr td").find(":checked").parent().parent().children)(.eq(5).append(document.getElementById("modwho").value);
    $("#tblmod").fadeOut("slow");


});
```

The table looks like this:

```
<table id='tblmod' width='80%' align='center' >
<tr bgcolor='white'>
<td width='15%'>
Enter Subject<input type="text" id="modsubject" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter Location<input type="text" id="modwhere" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter When<input type="text" id="modwhen" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter Time<input type="text" id="modtime" width="15%">
</td>
<td width='15%'>
Enter With Who<input type="text" id="modwho" width="15%">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th align="right" style=border-width:0px><button type="button" id="btnsavechanges" value="Save New Changes" >Save Changes</button></th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to explain what you have tried, what errors you are finding, what your question actually is, what your table update html+js looks like.

Comment: im trying to update a row in a table with data taken from the following table.
and nothing happens.thats the problem..no compailer/debugger errors..working with eclipse 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a data-binding framework.  I have been using knockoutjs recently and I like it.  The amount of code I write to do complicated UIs is far smaller when using Knockout.

Basically, you would bind the HTML by just adding a `data-bind` property to the element.  Then, when someone changes a value, it is immediately updated in your viewmodel.  If you pull in new data from an AJAX request, it will update your UI too.

More info here: http://knockoutjs.com/

I strongly suggest this as it will help you write cleaner, more manageable code, and do so faster.  You are going to be "reinventing the wheel" by handling everything "manually" as you are asking to do.

Comment: im a beginner with jQuery, so if there isn't a way to do that in jQuery ill go and try you suggestion..i really want to stay between the boundaries that i set at the moment.
thanks a lot though.

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael It can definitively be done using only jQuery, it's just going to be much more difficult to cover every corner case.  In contrast, a framework like Knockout handles those for you.  I understand the reluctance to take on too many new things at once, but, I think you would be better off learning it now.  BTW, jQuery and Knockout are totally compatible.  They are meant to solve very different issues.  Knockout is data-binding, jQuery is lower level API that handles DOM manipulation and cross-browser compliance.

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael Is what working with Eclipse?  Are you using Eclipse as an IDE for whatever you are writing JS/jQuery for?

Comment: yes, im working with Eclipse.
andi want to know  if Knockout is supported by Eclipse..i mean if there is a way to add a reference between eclipse 4.1 and knockout or smth like that?

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael I only use Eclipse for Android development.  I use gedit/vim for everything else, so, I am not familiar with it past Android.  Knockoutjs is **just** a javascript library, you include it just like jQuery.  There should not be any special support needed for it.