# Updating Table rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row, updating

Suppose you have a html table:

```
<table id="data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($arrData as $arrRecord) { ?>
        <tr id="tr_<?php echo $arrRecord["id"]; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $arrRecord["username"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $arrRecord["fname"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $arrRecord["lname"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And you have a JSON object:

```
objUser = {"id":12,"username":"j.smith","fname":"john","lname":"smith"};
```

And you want to change that record within the corresponding table row (assuming that this table already has a row with id="tr_12"):

```
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(1).html(objUser.id);
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(2).html(objUser.username);
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(3).html(objUser.fname);
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(4).html(objUser.lname);
```

Is there a faster/cleaner way of updating table rows using jQuery, than this last shown code block?

Comment: Try using: http://knockoutjs.com/ as explained  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159279/updating-a-table-row-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there may be a couple things you could do

```
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(1).html(objUser.id);
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(2).html(objUser.username);
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(3).html(objUser.fname);
$('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(4).html(objUser.lname);
```

Could become:

```
$this = $('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td");
$this.eq(1).html(objUser.id);
// And so on
```

You could do an outright replacements if it already exists

```
if ($('#tr_' + objUser.id).length) {
    var newHtml = '<td>' + .objUser.username + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + objUser.fname + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + objUser.lname + '</td>';
    $('#tr_' + objUser.id).html(newHtml);
}
```

Comment: Some ideas for thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    var objUser = {"id":2,"username":"j.smith","fname":"john","lname":"smith"};
    var objKeys = ["username", "fname", "lname"];

    $('#tr_' + objUser.id + ' td').each(function(i) {
        $(this).text(objUser[objKeys[i]]);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/5mXu8/)

Comment: +1 because I thought this was a very interesting answer! Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution, but a little bit shorter

```
 for(var i = 0; i < objUser.length; i++)
 {
    $('#tr_' + objUser.id).find("td").eq(i + 1).html(Object.keys(objUser)[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Can you reference a JSON object 'objUser[i]', where i is a numeric key  if the keys are not themselves numeric?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.each in Jquery

```
var i=1;var row=$('#tr_' + objUser.id);
$.each(objUser, function(key, element) {
  row.find("td").eq(i + 1).html(element);i+=1;
});
```

maybe it's longer,but you can forget the attr name.
the answer given by @jQuery00 is shorter,but I can't run it...

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your starting HTML has 3 `<TD>` cells with the id placed in the `<TR>`, while your Javascript creates 4 `<TD>` cells with the id placed in one of them.

If you can add an `id` attribute to the cells (perhaps like `"td_12_username"`), it would be easier to match them in a loop to ensure correct data is placed:

```
$.each(objUser, function(key, v){
  // Forces to skip the "id" key, otherwise sets value into the matching <TD>
  key !== "id" && $("#td_"+ objUser.id+ "_"+ key).html(val);
});
```

Otherwise, if you assume the order of the JSON object and order of cells will remain consistent, you could do as @jQuery00 suggested. Except start the counter at 1 if you don't want the id as a cell. And i'd suggest `children()` over `find()` in this case as it only looks at direct children of the `<TR>`, not all possible descendants.